# The APKs are not same when build from ant and adt

Tags: android, ant, apk, adt

I have an android project. I can release it to apk both from ADT in Eclipse and ant in command line. The the apk files are not same. 
I unzipped the apk files and compared the content. The main difference is the classes.dex file. The file compiled from ADT is a little smaller than from the ant.

Why they are not same ? Which is better when I release my app to users ?

Answer (score 2):

`Why are they not the same?` -- it's likely that there is some subtle compiler flag difference, leading to slight output differences.

`Which is better when I release my app to users?` -- the version you performed your testing with. It's probable that there will be no appreciable difference between the two, however if one binary is tested while the other is not, I would need a good reason to distribute the untested version (and I don't think such a reason exists).